# Outlook 2016 - Error message "None Default Email Program" but there is one

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016

One of our users has this message that pops up from time to time on his desktop.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du32p.png)

> *There is no email program associated to perform the requested action. Please install an email program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel*

The message appears from time to time but it is not connected to a specific action.
He told us that it appears generally when he moves a .msg to his file explorer but it is not systematic.
The problem is that the user’s PC is in the domain and we have a GPO that forces the default email program to be Outlook 2016 so the association is already created and existent.
Is there a way to resolve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the default Mail app, please also check default apps by portocol:

1. Open control Panel > Default Programs > Set your default programs.
2. Scroll down to find the option “Choose default apps by file type”
3. Make sure .msg is set to Outlook.

[image]

4. Go back and select “Choose default apps by protocol”
5. Make “MailTo” protocol is set to Outlook.

[image]

If none of this helps, there could be something wrong with the registry settings. Try steps in [this similar thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3ecd683c-1ffb-41b1-98e6-a6da6de62260/default-mail-program?forum=outlook) to delete Outlook key and then repair Office.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We already looked for that and Outlook is the default program for these two. In addition, it is also the default program for more file types and protocols. Please find the link with the file types and protocols attached to Outlook : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GjA7.png  Thanks for the link provided!

Comment: So issue still continues after deleting the registry?

Comment: Yes, the issue still continues after that. We tried the offline and the online reparation of Outlook but the problem is still present.

Comment: In this case,let's reset outlook settings via rename Outlook registry key. Please backup registry before making modification! HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook
Rename it to Outlook-1